# How to get label from the intent-filter in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest, android-sharing

I am making custom sharing dialog box. So, I want to list all applications from device which can have the SEND action. Sample code:

```
<activity android:name=".SomeActivity"> 
    <intent-filter android:label="@string/short_app_name"   
      android:icon="@drawable/test_icon"
      android:label="@string/long_activity_title"> 
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />  
    </intent-filter> 
</activity>
```

I can easily get the label from the activity tag from ResolveInfo, but I am not able to find a way to get the label from intent-filter programmatically. So let us know is there any way to get the label from intent-filter for respective activity from manifest?

Answer (score 1):

You're wrong. `ResolveInfo` gives you the `<intent-filter>` icon and label. `ActivityInfo` pulls from the `<activity>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick code sample that does just this, which I wrote after reading your question and the answer by @j__m plus some other resources:

```
        Intent i2 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PROCESS_TEXT);
        i2.setType("text/plain");
        PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
        List<ResolveInfo> infos = manager.queryIntentActivities(i2,
                 PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
        for (ResolveInfo info : infos) {
            try {
                Log.d("TEST", "Package name: ", info.activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName);
                Resources res = manager.getResourcesForApplication(info.activityInfo.applicationInfo);
                int labelRes = info.labelRes;
                if (labelRes == 0)
                    labelRes = info.activityInfo.labelRes;
                Log.d("TEST", " - Title: ", res.getString(labelRes));
            } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException ignore) {}
        }
```